# sample n number of cards from a deck using rstudio

Tags: r, playing-cards

```
#initialize suits

suits <-c ("Heart", "Diamond", "Club", "Spade")
cards <-c ("Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten")
deck <- data.frame(suits = character(0), cards = character(0))

numOfDeck = 1

while (numOfDeck == 1){
      for (i in suits){
          for (j in cards){
               deck <- rbind.data.frame(deck, cbind.data.frame(j, i))
     }
   }
   numOfDeck = numOfDeck + 1
}
hand <- sample (1:52, 5)
```

From this, I get the deck and five random numbers. I want to assign those random numbers to the rank in the deck such that: if i get 5 as my first random number, it should print Two Heart as that's what i have in position 5. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the deck that you want using `outer`.

```
DECK = outer(cards, suits, paste)
DECK[5]
[1] "Two Heart"

hand <- sample (1:52, 5)
DECK[hand]
[1] "Eight Diamond" "Seven Spade"   "King Heart"    "Ace Spade"    
[5] "Seven Diamond"
```